# How to find out if six-digit consecutive numbers (such as 123456, 345678, and 789012) appears anywhere in a given string

Tags: python-3.x, list, find

I have done something but I believe there must be some easy way to do it.

```
import re

data = open('somestring.txt','r')
whole_text = data.read().replace('\n','')
whole_text = whole_text.replace(' ','')

L1 ='0123456789'
List=[]
for i in range(1,11):
    L = ''
    for j in range(6):
        s = str((int(L1[j])+i-1)%10)
        L += s
    List.append(L)

y = re.findall(somestring)
```

Comment: for example, the given string might be pi or something

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if re is necessary here. You could simply use the "in" keyword.

```
my_list = ['12345','345678']
my_number = '123'
for number in my_list:
    if my_number in number:
        print(number)
```

this will print "12345".

Comment: What if my_list = [‘12345’ , ‘345678’]                and my_number =‘ 12345000019374719304761634567812344...’ (might be 1 million digits).                             What I want to do is to find all ‘12345’ in my_number.

Comment: Just reverse the two like you just said, and adjust the iteration accordingly. 
`for number in my_list:
    if number in my_big_number:
        print(number)`
One thing to note; if you know some numbers may be very large, then this implementation might not be suitable for production level code.